# Is there any user space tool available for eMMC to perform diagnostic Test and Performance test in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

We are using Micron eMMC 60GB. I want to validate its performance (like temperature and UPL count). Is there any tool available for it in Linux?How do i check the lifetime of it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

Linux kernel developers have developed `mmc_test` as a unit-testing module to test `emmc` and made it as a part of linux kernel source code. You need to build your kernel with `CONFIG_MMC_TEST` enabled as a `LKM`. Please follow the following steps:

1. `#insmod mmc_test.ko`
2. unbind the mmc block driver: 
   `#echo mmc0:b368 > /sys/bus/mmc/drivers/mmcblk/unbind`
3. bind the `mmc_test` driver: 
   `#echo mmc0:b368 > /sys/bus/mmc/drivers/mmc_test/bind`
4. mount the debugfs if you don't mount for debugfs: 
   `#mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`
5. After mount, you can `cat` for: `"/sys/kernel/debug/mmc0/mmc0:b368/test"`
6. `#echo "test number" > /sys/kernel/debug/mmc0/mmc0\:b368/test` 
   you can see the "test number" using  `#cat /sys/kernel/debug/mmc0/mmc0\:b368/testlist`

I have been able to test my `emmc` for testing `trim` features without any issues!